# Return array from external function and get the result

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a problem in Java.
I have this function "fillArray()" and I need this function return an array. The arrays values are get by JSON.

The code of this function is the next:

```
  public String[] fillArray(){

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://api.mysite.com/v1/countries",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                        final String[] countries = new String[jsonArray.length()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject country = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String country_name = country.getString("country_name");
                            countries[i] = country_name;
                            Log.v("NAME:", country_name);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return countries;
}
```

I can return the array, I get the error "Cannot resolver symbol countries".

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Which line gives the error?